# VS 2015 with Java

Tags: java, visual-studio-2015

I want to start a java console application project “hello world” in Visual Studio 2015 – NuGet also loaded -and obtain the error

An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension.
You can get more information by examining the file ... ActivityLog.xml

The ActivityLog.xml is listing the error

“A MEF Component threw an exception at runtime: Microsoft.VisualStudio.ExtensibilityHosting.InvalidMEFCacheException: The Visual Studio component cache is out of date. Please restart Visual Studio.”

The “hello world” project was loaded into the VS editor nevertheless.

This error apparently has shown up also but in different context as many entries regarding this error are found on the internet. Then I found the proposed solution:

“
Normally when you see an error containing "CompositionFailedException" it is due to the extension cache being out of date or corrupt. After installing any new component, it should rebuild this by scanning the file system (and caches it to avoid needing to do it on every launch).
One way to force this to be rebuilt is:
Delete the contents of the folder at "%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache"
Run "DevEnv.exe /setup" (this is under "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE", but should be on your PATH if you open a Developer Command Prompt).
Next time you launch VS it will take a while to rebuild (which may be part of the delay above), but should resolve any MEF errors.
“

I then deleted the content of ComponentModelCache and tried to run DevEnv.exe /setup. But the system prevented the process to run because of “higher rights required”. Setting me up as administrator in windows had no effect.

I am not sufficiently familiar with VS to set it up such that I can run DevEnv.exe /setup and therefore I do not know whether this is the solution to avoiding the exception.

So my question is how to set VS such that I can run DevEnv.exe /setup and also whether at all this would solve my problem. I am sorry if the problem has been solved already and I did not find the solution.

Comment: Just wondering: if you are not familiar with that IDE; why do you want to use it? Of all the IDEs out there suited for Java, I didn't even know that Visual Studio ... is in that list. There are for sure many products such as IntelliJ or Eclipse that are much better suited for Java development.

Comment: Second GhostCat and also want to mention [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/) IDE ... of all the IDE's that come to mind regarding Java, VS would have been probably one of the last on my list. I guess I'd rather use vi ...

Comment: @GhostCat: I have been using VS for all my C++ Programms. Also, Java is working in VS 2013. How to use VS for Java is shown in a Youtube video. My issue is why do I get the error in VS 2015 and how to obtain the rights to run DevEnv.exe /setup.

Comment: @HaraldHubbes Good look with that then. Obviously, your question didn't create helpful answers so far; thus I would rather turn to some MS development forums and ask there. As you might have guessed by now, there might be very very few people around here using VS for java related work.

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for the suggestion, I will try. Perhaps somebody will still wake up.